# check if string formed using stated set of rules or not

Tags: java, string

Check if string formed using stated set of rules or not. Generated using the following rules:

> **a.** the string begins with an 'a'
>
> **b.** each 'a' is followed by nothing or an 'a' or "bb"
>
> **c.** each "bb" is followed by nothing or an 'a'

I tried the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scn.nextLine();
    boolean b = false;
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'a') {
        if (str.charAt(1) == 'b') {
            if (str.charAt(2) == 'b') {
                b = true;
            } else
                b = false;

        } else
            b = false;
    } else
        b = false;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

is the code all right...???
For input = aab the output should be false and for input =abba the output should be true.

Comment: This question belongs here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you try running the code? What were your results?

Comment: for the above two test cases it works fine but when i try this code on an online coding site it is falling certain test cases i dont know why.

Comment: What is that online judge? Also, your code will give nullpointer if the string is only "a"

Comment: You need to loop through the entire string, not just the first 3 chars. Ex "abbaaaabba".

Comment: yes your are right i should use loop , didn't came to my mind as i just saw those 2 test cases and tried to code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regular expressions are allowed, the pattern `(a+(bb)?)+` matches strings that follow the rule (And doesn't match strings that don't).

Otherwise, Your approach can't possibly work without some kind of loop, because the string `aaaaaaaaaaa` does match the pattern.

Consider the following method, which should handle it.

```
private static boolean stringMatches(String s) {
  // Handle empty and null cases first.
  if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) return false;

  // So long as the string continues to match the pattern, keep stripping
  // characters from it until it is empty. If you reach empty, it matches the pattern.
  while (! s.isEmpty()) {
    // If the first character isn't 'a', we don't match; return false.
    if (s.charAt(0) != 'a') {
      return false;
    }

    // Check for abb, if so strip all of that, otherwise strip just the a
    if (s.length() >= 3 && "abb".equals(s.substring(0,3)) {
      s = s.substring(3);
    } else {
      s = s.substring(1);
    }
  }
  // Reached empty string, return true.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: yes your are right i should use loop , didn't came to my mind as i just saw those 2 test cases and tried to code for it .

Answer (score 2):

This is my snippet:

```
def checkAB(str):
    if len(str) == 0:
        return True
    if len(str) == 1:
        if str == 'a':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if str[0] == 'a':
        return checkAB(str[1:])
    elif str[0] == 'b':
        if str[1] == 'b':
            return checkAB(str[2:])
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Try to read the boolean and print the output in string "true" or "false". In my case i made a mistake here by directly returning boolean value.

One more snippet:

```
def checkAB(str):
    if (len(str) == 0):
        return True

    if (str[0] == 'a'):
        if (len(str[1:]) > 1 and str[1:3] == 'bb'):
            return checkAB(str[3:])
        else:
            return checkAB(str[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: How does this make sure that  `'a' is followed by nothing or an 'a' ` and  `each "bb" is followed by nothing or an 'a'?`

Answer (score 1):

This is the recursive approach:

```
public static boolean checkAB(String s) 
{
    if (s.length()==0) 
        return true;
    if (s.charAt(0) != 'a')
        return false;
    if (s.length() >= 3 && "abb".equals(s.substring(0,3)))
        return checkAB(s.substring(3));
    else
        return checkAB(s.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is my attempt at this code in c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void fastIO()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
}
bool checkAB(string input)
{
    if (input.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (input.size() == 1)
    {
        if (input[0] == 'a')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    if (input[0] == 'a')
    {
        return checkAB(input.substr(1));
    }
    if (input[0] == 'b' && input[1] == 'a')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (input[0] == 'b' && input[1] == 'b' && (input[2] == 'a' || input[2] == '\0'))
    {
        return checkAB(input.substr(2));
    }
    else
        return false;
}
int main()
{
    fastIO();
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    // the following if statement is just to ensure that if the first charachter is not 'a' then don't proceed at all.
    if (input[0] != 'a')
    {
        cout << "false";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << (checkAB(input.substr(1)) ? "true" : "false");
    }

    return 0;
}
```