# Recursive String Matching - giving opposite output on one test case

Tags: string, recursion, data-structures, substring, string-matching

**Passed 5/6 Test Cases and 3/3 sample cases. Failing one hidden Test Case**

1. The string begins with an `a`.
2. Each `a` is followed by nothing or an `a` or `bb`.
3. Each `bb` is followed by nothing or an `a`.

If all the rules are followed by the given string, return true otherwise return false.

> Sample Input: abbaabb
>
> Sample Output: true

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool checkAB(char input[])
{
    bool answer = true;
    if (input[0] == 'P' && input[1] == '\0')
        return true;
    if (input[0] != 'P')
    {
        if (input[0] == 'a' && (input[1] == '\0' || input[1] == 'a' || (input[1] == 'b' && input[2] == 'b')))
        {
            input[0] = 'P';
            return checkAB(input);
        }
    }
    else if (input[0] == 'P')
    {
        if (input[1] == 'a' && (input[2] == '\0' || input[2] == 'a' || (input[2] == 'b' && input[3] == 'b')))
            answer = true;
        else if (input[1] == 'a' && (input[2] == 'b' && input[3] == 'a'))
            answer = false;

        if (input[1] == 'b' && input[2] == 'b' && (input[3] == '\0' || input[3] == 'a'))
            answer = true;
        else if (input[1] == 'b' && input[2] == 'b' && input[3] == 'b')
            answer = false;
    }

    if (answer == false)
        return false;
    else
    {
        input[1] = 'P';
        return checkAB(input + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    bool ans;
    cin >> input;
    ans = checkAB(input);
    if (ans)
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false" << endl;
}
```

I'm Iterating though the input array and marking the `index 0` as `'P'` for `PASS` recursively and checking the consecutive inputs for the above `3 rules`. As soon as any one rule is broken i make `answer` `false` recursively return or else keeping the answer `true` and index 0 as `'P'` I keep moving forward and at the end when `(input[0] == 'P' && input[1] == '\0')` I have reached end of string I return.

Comment: It's hard to figure out exactly what your algorithm is doing, but you could just check the input string against the regex `(a+(bb)?)+`. See this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366942/check-if-string-formed-using-stated-set-of-rules-or-not

Comment: Your code will fail horribly if `input[0] == '\0'`. Looks like it will go into an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: Also, your code assumes that the only input to your function will be strings containing the characters 'a' and 'b'. If somebody passed `"food"` to your function, it would return `true`. Your initial statement, `answer = true;` assumes that the string is good, but you don't rule out all invalid cases. Probably a better idea is to assume that the string is not good: set `answer = false` at the beginning, and explicitly set `answer = true` for all good cases.

Comment: constraint was that string with only a and b will  b given